# Devise Affiliates System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I was wondering if there was a gem for a simple affiliates system for devise. What I was looking for is that "Bob" can give "Joe" his ref link. Then when Joe signs up, it gets put in the DB that Joe was brought in by Bob. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great gem to start with: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable With a little tweaking (mainly just grabbing the url), you can set it up as a affiliates system. Another pro with this is that "Bob" can enter "Joe's" email address and "Joe" will get an email with the link!